# Table ignoring styling color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using JavaScript to identify rows with specific values and paint the entire row red, the code itself seems to be running fine, because I can see it is indeed adding the style to the table row, but it's only painting one row (maybe only the last?)

Can you guys help me understand whats happening?

Just to context, I'm using a python library called pretty-html-table that auto creates these tables with pre-set html components.

I also tried adding specific class to the tr and adding !important to the style tag, like these:

```
$('.dataframe tr').filter(function(){
   return $.trim($('td', this).eq(0).text())=="Sim";
}).addClass('redcolor');
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/douglasdcr/q1u67259/2/)

Or snipper below

```js
$('.dataframe tr').filter(function(){
   return $.trim($('td', this).eq(0).text())=="Sim";
}).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<table border="0" class="dataframe">
<thead>
  <tr style="text-align: right;">
    <th style="background-color: #FFFFFF;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;color: #808080;text-align: left;border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">Bloq?</th>
    <th style="background-color: #FFFFFF;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;color: #808080;text-align: left;border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">TES</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #EDEDED;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">Não</td>
    <td style="background-color: #EDEDED;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">218</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: red;">
    <td style="background-color: white; color: black;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">Sim</td>
    <td style="background-color: white; color: black;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">236</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:red;">
    <td style="background-color: #EDEDED;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">Sim</td>
    <td style="background-color: #EDEDED;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">237</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: _"because I can see it is indeed adding the style to the table row, but it's only painting one row (maybe only the last?)"_ - the last row already has red text color based on the HTML and CSS alone. Your JS code currently doesn't even run either here in the snippet or the fiddle, because you did not embed jQuery into either of them to begin with, so it only throws an error that `$` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem seems to be that you are trying to set the color on the `tr` and not the `td`, so add `.find("td")` before your `.css('color', 'red')`

**Demo**

```js
$('.dataframe tr').filter(function() {
  return $.trim($('td', this).eq(0).text()) == "Sim";
}).find("td").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th style="background-color: #FFFFFF;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;color: #808080;text-align: left;border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">Bloq?</th>
      <th style="background-color: #FFFFFF;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;color: #808080;text-align: left;border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">TES</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #EDEDED;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">Não</td>
      <td style="background-color: #EDEDED;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">218</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color: red;">
      <td style="background-color: white; color: black;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">Sim</td>
      <td style="background-color: white; color: black;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">236</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:red;">
      <td style="background-color: #EDEDED;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">Sim</td>
      <td style="background-color: #EDEDED;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: medium;text-align: left;padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;width: auto">237</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It worked, but funny that tr should also work, right? Like it painted the last one. On a large dataframe, painting all the td would be slower than paint the entire tr, or not? Just out of curiosity and trying to understand the logic

Comment: @ddddddd the table _cells_ in your second row explicitly have `color: black` set via inline styles, so of course setting a color for the table _row_ does not overwrite that.

Comment: when I tried the .addClass instead, I used color:red !important; to the tr, even that wouldnt be necessary to overwrite?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the colors , delete `color: black;` style from second row `td` tags.